# What's this visualization artifact and how can I avoid it?

Tags: display, hdmi, screen-tearing

I bought a new laptop that I connect to the same external monitor than before, but now I'm noticing something when viewing videos in that monitor. It happens too when scrolling images or with 2D games like MAME.

It's a horizontal line with a bevel in the middle, that is not always at the same height, it moves vertically as shown in the gif linked below

It's a LCD DELL E207WFP connected to the laptop with a HDMI-DVI cable

Graphics card: Intel(R) Iris Xe Graphics (TGL GT2)

[GIF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2R1HU.gif) (warning: cringey 90s video)

[image: still image]

**UPDATE:**

The integrated laptop screen rate is 60.0 Hz, this may have something to do with the problem. I have tried with the integrated laptop screen on and off

Comment: Have you checked that you've set the new laptop to the same refresh rate on the monitor as the old one (where you presumably weren't having the same problem)?

Comment: @pigeonburger I don't have the old laptop anymore to check it, but the monitor specs say 60 Hz, and Win10 reports 59,883 Hz (doesn't let me change it)

Comment: Should we assume the artifact does not appear on the integrated screen? I'm asking because the question does not state this *explicitly*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks a lot like a common [screen tearing artifact](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Screen_tearing). Usually this is fixed by installing proper graphics drivers and then enabling VSYNC on the output. Your video player is likely to have an option for VSYNC and [so does MAME](https://itstillworks.com/12612260/mame-vertical-sync-options).

If the problem persists for the video player, try using `mpv` or, if you're on Windows, use MPC.

Comment: I hadn't thought of trying different applications, now I tried and I see that mpv works fine, Chrome+Netflix works fine, but Chrome+YouTube shows tearing. Firefox works fine after enabling hardware acceleration, so that's what I'll use for YouTube